# nodeJs soap call https wsdl url has Error: Invalid WSDL URL:

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, wsdl

I have wsdl url like `https://example.com/TokenService?wsdl` Which is given from the gateway company.
When i call wsdl url by below function :

```
let wsdlURL = "https://example.com/TokenService?wsdl";
let soap = require('soap');

soap.createClient(wsdlURL, function(err, client) {
  console.log(client)
})
```

In server response client is `undefined` and i get error look like

> Invalid WSDL URL:https://example.com/TokenService?wsdlxsd=1

I contacted gateway the company and replied to me don't request in `port 443` because your request was blocked in port 443.

How can Call wsdl yourl without prevent check ssl and redirect to port 443 ?

Comment: Can you check that URL and see whether the XML data shows up in browser

Comment: @Batman The wsdl address is correct.And i can see other parameters in `xml` file.